# What is the OverloadAttribute used for?

Tags: javascript, .net, windows-runtime, overloading, windows-store-apps

So in designing an API I've found some problems with Javascript and overloads and all that fun stuff. One thing I think may help is the `OverloadAttribute`. The reason for this question though is that I can not find any documentation on what this does. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.overloadattribute.aspx) gives very helpful information

> Identifies the method as an overload in a language that supports
>   overloading.

Obviously, I need a bit more information than that. So, what exactly is this used for? What is the `string method` parameter of the constructor used for?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation indicates, the `OverloadAttribute` is for use by languages that do not support overloading.  For example, consider writing Windows Runtime code at the ABI layer using IDL and C++ (not C++/CX).  In IDL, you cannot overload interface functions:  each function of an interface must have a different name.

Let's take a look at an example.  Here's the definition of `IUriRuntimeClassFactory` from the Windows.Foundation.idl file, which you can find in the Windows 8 SDK:

```
interface IUriRuntimeClassFactory : IInspectable
{
    [overload("CreateUri")] HRESULT CreateUri([in] HSTRING uri, [out] [retval] Windows.Foundation.Uri** instance);
    [overload("CreateUri")] HRESULT CreateWithRelativeUri([in] HSTRING baseUri, [in] HSTRING relativeUri, [out] [retval] Windows.Foundation.Uri** instance);
}
```

The two interface functions are declared with different names in IDL.  Both functions are annotated with the IDL `overload` attribute.  This attribute tells the IDL compiler that both of these member functions are *logically* overloads of `CreateUri`.

When the midlrt IDL compiler generates a WinMD file from this IDL, it will swap the overload name and the interface function name so that in metadata, both of these interface functions will have the name `CreateUri`, and both functions will have the `OverloadAttribute` applied to them with the original name (`CreateUri` for the first, and `CreateWithRelativeUri` for the second).  You can observe this by taking a look at the metadata in the reference Windows.winmd using ildasm.

When you generate IDL from a WinMD, the reverse transformation happens:  interface functions that are annotated with an `OverloadAttribute` are named using the name provided by that attribute.  This allows lossless round-tripping between IDL and WinMD.

Comment: So basically, it's useless outside of C++/IDL?

Comment: That is one example of where it is used.  Any other language projection could use the overload information, though.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. I have `[Overload("Foo")]void FooBar(string x)` and `[Overload("Foo")]void FooBang(SomeClass x)` and get a compiler error `multiple overloads of Foo have the same overload name "Foo", specified by using Windows.Foundation.Metadata.OverloadAttribute`

Comment: ...Or with some tricks, I can make it compile, but it'll never show up from calling programs as the method name specified in the overload attribute

Comment: Well, your example is backwards.  In the C++/CX and .NET projections (C# and VB.NET), the mapping is direct:  the actual name of the function in the source is what is used for the name of the function in metadata.  The string in the `OverloadAttribute` is simply stored in the attribute for use by consumers that do not support overloading (like IDL/C++).

Comment: So, you'd need to have`[Overload("FooBar")] void Foo(string x)` and `[Overload("FooBang")] void Foo(SomeClass x)`.  The resulting WinMD will define the class as having two member functions, both named `Foo`, each with the specified `OverloadAttribute`.  If you generate an IDL file from that WinMD, you'll see that the interface in IDL has two member functions, named `FooBar` and `FooBang`, both with the IDL attribute `[overload("Foo")]`.

Comment: The `OverloadAttribute` simply says "in languages that don't support overloading, use this name for this overload."

Comment: So because everything in WinRT currently supports overloading(at least by parameter count), it's currently useless

Comment: IDL does not support overloading and IDL is one of the supported ways to define (and make use of) Windows Runtime types.

Comment: Please note that "Foo as described above is *NOT* legal.  Windows Runtime overloads must differ by arity (number of "in" parameters), both Foo methods above have the same arity, so they are illegal.